# How to dynamically declare a cursor in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, cursor, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to use a dynamic query to declare a cursor. Basically I have the name of the table-valued function I will use for the cursor as a column of a table so I must declare the cursor using a SQL statement.

The problem is that T-SQL doesn't recognize `myCursor` as a valid cursor.

```
DECLARE @ColumnA nvarchar(250)
DECLARE @ColumnB nvarchar(250)
DECLARE @FunctionName nvarchar(250)
DECLARE @RecordId nvarchar(250)
DECLARE @sqlStatement nvarchar(MAX)

SET @sqlStatement = 'DECLARE myCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT * FROM ' + @FunctionName + '(''' + @RecordId + ''')'

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlStatement

OPEN myCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @ColumnA, @ColumnB

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @ColumnA, @ColumnB

    FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @ColumnA, @ColumnB
END

CLOSE myCursor
DEALLOCATE myCursor
```

Any help or workarounds are welcome.

EDIT: I've solved the problem by declaring the cursor before and using output from sqlstatement to pass values.

DECLARE @myCursor CURSOR

SET @sqlStatement = 'SET @myCursor = CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT * FROM ' + @FunctionName + '(''' + @RecordId + ''');OPEN @myCursor;'

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlStatement, N'@Placeholder nvarchar(250), @Placeholdervalue nvarchar(250), @myCursor CURSOR OUTPUT', @Placeholder = @Placeholder, @Placeholdervalue = @Placeholdervalue, @myCursor = @myCursor OUTPUT

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/179361). What are you actually trying to achieve? I cannot imagine this is the best solution. In 10 years of working with SQL Server, I can honestly say I have never encountered a scenario that that would require a dynamically declared cursor. How do you know your function will return at least two columns? How do you know those columns will be `nvarchar(250)`? How do you know that a valid function name has been issued?  How do you know that your function accepts a single nvarchar(250) parameter?

Comment: @GarethD you might need to do this in a ETL, for migration of data or loading a Data Warehouse

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best solution but if you really have to do this - an easier way is to use a dynamic SQL to load the data you need into a global temp table first. The dynamic SQL statement is much simpler i.e.:

```
SET @sqlStatement = 'SELECT * INTO ##MyGlobalTemp FROM ' + @FunctionName + '(''' + @RecordId + ''')'
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlStatement
```

Then use a regular (non-dynamic) cursor to loop through the ##MyGlobalTemp table (and don't forgot to drop the temp after you are finished).

i.e.:

```
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT column1, column2, etc.. FROM  ##MyGlobalTemp...... etc..
```

Dynamic cursors could get hairy. Just make sure the temp has a global (##) scope.

Hope this helps.